# How to transform this excel dataset in pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I need your tip. I have a terrible excel dataset that has a few problems:
[image: pic1]

1. it starts with row 3 and column B
2. columns are not merged
3. I should delete all "Revenues with discount" and leave only "Revenues without discount"
4. I should delete all rows and columns "total"

In short, I should transform dataset, so it should look like this:
[image: pic2]

Thank you in advance from the begginer in data analytics :)

P.s. sorry, I could not upload the values as a table, that is why I attach images

Comment: can you share the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the excel file into pandas dataframe. using 'header' takes all the multi-headers from the excel. Use the print statement to display the column names.

```
df= pd.read_excel('../../Downloads/Book1.xlsx', header=[0, 1, 2])
print(df.columns)
```

The next set of codes below is a bit of manipulation on the column names. we are iterating through the above column multi-index names which are in tuple format, and parsing only the needed information from there. Then you create new column names that gets appended to 'cols_required' list and we also have the multi-index column names.

```
col_names, cols_required = [],[]# initiating empty lists to hold the multiindex names and the new column names
for col in df.columns:
    if 'Unnamed' in str(col[0]) or 'Unnamed' in str(col[1]):# use print statements to see how these tuples look
        cols_required.append(col[2])
        col_names.append(col)
    elif 'with' in str(col[2]) or 'Total' in str(col[1]):
        pass #ignoring columns that have "with","total" in the names
    else:
        cols_required.append(str(col[0])+'_'+str(col[1])+'_'+str(col[2]))
        col_names.append(col)
```

Now from the above piece of code, we have the multi-index column names as well as the new names. we filter only the required columns and then assign the new names.

```
df = df[col_names] 
df.columns = cols_required
df.head()
```

I have used the exact column names that you have provided.Please tweak the manipulation of column names as per your requisites.

Comment: Thank you, but I recieved mistake "Passed header=[0,1,2] are too many rows for this multi_index of columns"

Comment: Hi Nikita, Are there three rows that constitute the header? If there are three rows of headings as shown in your sample, this should work. Can you provide a sample file?

Comment: Actually, I found another mistake in code so your algorithm worked, thank you!